# How to import global styles so that reset.scss does not affect the styles of the storybook itself

Tags: css, sass, storybook

I started to deal with the wonderful storybook library but I found an unpleasant moment for myself, I have a file in the project that resets all styles reset.scss and it is connected accordingly in the mountain and then I import all my global styles for the project, I decided to connect it in .storybook/preview.ts file so that my components are true because in the global scss file I connect the changes and everything else that I need to work, but I noticed that my file also affects the styles of the storybook itself, and I would like it to affect the ticks on the components themselves.

A working example without my global styles file:
[image]

And accordingly with the file:
[image]

How can I fix this? Like, I could cascadingly rewrite these styles specifically for storybook, but that would affect the true look of my components, and I wouldn't want that result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved this problem by clinging to the `docblock-argstable` block and deleting unnecessary styles.

[image]

I will continue to observe what other blocks are broken in the documentation and correct them according to the original ones.

Maybe someone will post a more succinct solution.